# How to upload/select images from WP media library using vue 2

Tags: wordpress, vue.js

I am Using Vue 2 in Wordpress admin page , Need to upload image or selecting image from WP media. Is this possible to open Wp Media uploader in vuejs? Thanks in advance..

Comment: This may be of some interest https://github.com/bucky355/vue-wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function.php enqueue the media file.

```
if ( ! did_action( 'wp_enqueue_media' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_media();
}
```

Then vue page add button with click action,

```
media_upload() {
        let that = this;
        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function (props, attachment) {
            that.new_metal_image = attachment;
            console.log(that.new_metal_image);
        };
        wp.media.editor.open();
    }
```